# How to interpret output of rpart decision tree?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart

I need your help please in interpreting this: I am trying to predict suicide rate but confused about interpretation. for number 2 for example, for the group age 5-14, the suicide rate will be 0.35 which is 17.3%. Or for each person in that group 5-14, the probability of suicide is 17.3%?

Here is the function I used

```
rpart(log_suicides_per_100k~age+sex+ year +log_population + log_gdp_per_capita,data=train)


n= 21040 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
  * denotes terminal node

1) root 21040 33218.2800 1.8847770  
 2) age=5-14 years 3631   525.2584 0.3596050 *
 3) age=15-24 years,25-34 years,35-54 years,55-74 years,75+ years 17409 22485.1400 2.2028830  
  6) sex=female 9121  8035.2170 1.5364590  
   12) log_population< 10.35335 1358   987.9247 0.4001549 *
   13) log_population>=10.35335 7763  4987.1280 1.7352350 *
  7) sex=male 8288  5941.1340 2.9362870  
   14) age=15-24 years 1764  1271.1730 2.3873540 *
   15) age=25-34 years,35-54 years,55-74 years,75+ years 6524  3994.6980 3.0847110 *
```

[image]

Comment: There are functions to plot the tree, much easier to interpret then.

Comment: What function did produce this result? With what arguments? What is your data? It would be hard to give a good answer without more details.

Answer (score 2):

The expected suicide rate is 0.36, 17.3% of the samples fall into that leaf.

You can figure it out by reading this line:

```
node), split, n, deviance, yval
```

So

```
2) age=5-14 years 3631   525.2584 0.3596050 *
```

Translates to 3631 samples in this terminal leaf, with a deviance of 525 and a `yval` (the output) of 0.36.

Notice how the percentages approximately sum to 100% as well.

Comment: What is the 0.3596050 value ?